# Polyphormic deserialization without type in jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson, deserialization

I have the following classes, `ParentClass`, `Class A extends ParentClass` and `Class B extends ParentClass`, I would like to deserialize the following XML messages:

```
<A url="http://www.example.com></A> needs to be serialized as class A
```

and

```
<B url="http://www.example.com></B> needs to be serialized as class B
```

I have tried using the `JsonSubTypes` annotations.

```
@Getter
@JsonTypeInfo(use = NONE)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = A.class, name = "A"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = B.class, name = "B")
})
@XmlType(name = "ParentClass")
public abstract class ParentClass {
```

And using the

```
ParentClass entityEventBaseClass = XML_MAPPER.readValue(jsonString, XML_MAPPER.constructType(ParentClass));
```

But I am getting an error
`Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of`ParentClass`(no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information`

I am not able to modify the incoming messages and I see most of the time people use `type` to choose which subclass the framework should instantiate, what I am trying to achieve is deserialize based on the value of the root node in the XML.

If instead of the ParentClass I use `A.class` or `B.class` the code works, but once a message of the other type arrives it cause some troubles.

Comment: have you tried `XML_MAPPEr.configure(MapperFeature.INFER_CREATOR_FROM_CONSTRUCTOR_PROPERTIES,false);`? I am not 100%, but seems to be something funky regarding `jackson` and `lombok`

Comment: I am getting the same error, add that configuration does not help. thanks.